# Keep Getting "TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve algorithm problems, but I keep getting this error, and it frustrate me:

```
    var data = [".......", "...O...", "....O..", ".......", "OO.....", "OO....."]
    var R = 6;
    var C = 7;
    var N = 3;
    var cell = new Array(R);
    for (i=0; i<R; i++) {
        cell[i] = new Array(C);
    }
    for (i=0; i<R; i++) {
        var currentRow = data[i].split("");
        for (j=0; j<C; j++) {
            cell[i][j] = currentRow[j];
        }
    }
    for (x=0; x<=N; x++) {
        for (i=0; i<R; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<C; j++) {
                if (cell[i][j] == '.') {
                    cell[i][j] = 0;
                } else if (cell[i][j] == 'O') {
                    cell[i][j] = 1;
                } else if (cell[i][j] == 3) {
                    cell[i][j] = 0;
                    // Why are these following 4 LINES are not working???
                    cell[i + 1][j] = 0;
                    cell[i - 1][j] = 0;
                    cell[i][j + 1] = 0;
                    cell[i][j - 1] = 0;
                } else if (cell[i][j] >= 0) {
                    cell[i][j] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The culprit is when we are trying to use 2D array with some operation like

```
cell[i + 1][j] = 0;
cell[i - 1][j] = 0;
cell[i][j + 1] = 0;
cell[i][j - 1] = 0;
```

I dont know why but keep getting `TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined`

Comment: suppose that cell[0][1] is 3, how will your code work?

Comment: Thank you, thank you, I recognize it, i forgot to consider the possibility of [0]. Hahaha :)

Comment: I added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these lines of code are sometimes accessing out of bounds on your arrays. The code will work without the error message by changing those 4 lines to guarantee the access remains in bounds, like this:

```
                // Why are these following 4 LINES are not working???
                if (i < R - 1) {
                    cell[i + 1][j] = 0;
                }
                if (i > 0) {
                    cell[i - 1][j] = 0;
                } 
                if (j < C - 1) {
                    cell[i][j + 1] = 0;
                }
                if (j > 0) {
                    cell[i][j - 1] = 0;
                }
```

Here's a [link to a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vboughner/vdz58fff/) where I have placed the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

If the first horizontal or first vertical cell of your array is equal 3, than you can't do `i - 1` or `j -1`. Same thing if the last horizontal cell or the last vertical cell equals 3, you can't do `i + 1` or `j + 1`. So you just have to check wheter is not the first or the last vertical cell of your bidimensional array.